# Windows 10 going to sleep while on remote connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, sleep

I have a windows 10 desktop machine and want to run this machine for an infinite amount of time. To do so, the following changes are made on my machine.

[image]

With this change, I expect my machine to run for infinite time. However, machine goes into sleep mode after remote connection.

Please help me to keep machine awake for an infinite amount of time even after remote connection.

Comment: Try making a new power plan, and then setting the above settings in the new power plan.

Comment: Look in the system event log for power related events to explain why the system is going to sleep. Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.